# java.net.UnknownHostException: appengine.google.com

Tags: google-app-engine

Got this error. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Yesterday it was working fine but today I got these errors. I saw a known issue with this - [link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3131). But I didn't find any solution yet..

```
 Oct 16, 2012 4:01:59 PM com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory getVersion

INFO: Unable to access https://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java&release=1.7.1&timestamp=1345058163&api_versions=['1.0']
java.net.UnknownHostException: appengine.google.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory.getVersion(RemoteVersionFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.checkForUpdates(UpdateCheck.java:99)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.doNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.maybePrintNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:142)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:289)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:225)
Oct 16, 2012 4:01:59 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Oct 16, 2012 4:02:00 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed D:\WorkSpace\GAE\GST\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Oct 16, 2012 4:02:00 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed D:\WorkSpace\GAE\GST\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Oct 16, 2012 4:02:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Java 8 in your app engine application, you will need to include

```
<url-stream-handler> urlfetch </ url-stream-handler>
```

in `appengine-web.xml`.

[appengine-web.xml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#url-stream-handler)

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. It happened to me when I switched to java 8, but only on my non-billed-enabled projects, as explained in your link, or here : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests#java_8_runtime_vs_java_7_behavior

Comment: There should be no spaces around "urlfetch"

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are seeing this in your Eclipse IDE when you are trying to run the Eclipse Project as a Web Application.

The GAE plugin simply checks if there is an updated AppEngine SDK available for download. If there is a newer one than the one  you are currently using then it lets you know that. The error is because at that instance, there was probably a network error and it got not connect through. It is harmless as far as running your application is concerned.

But if your application is dependent on accessing some external network services, then chances are that they might fail also if the network issue persists in your development environment.

Comment: That was a good info..but  how do I configure my project to stop checking the updated AppEngine..

Comment: got it working.. : cmd->goto your home directory >mkdir .appcfg_no_nag   this will stop checking for the update and yourweb app willrun locally atleast..

Answer (score 1):

got it working.. : cmd->goto your home directory >mkdir .appcfg_no_nag this will stop checking for the update and yourweb app willrun locally atleast..

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to internet connection. I changed to other connection, it works

Answer (score 0):

You should add in **appengine-web.xml**:

```
<url-stream-handler> urlfetch </ url-stream-handler>
```

And also start using **java.net.URLConnection**,
Apache HttpClient is not gonna work for example.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests#java_8_runtime_vs_java_7_behavior