# SSLHandshakeException when issuing http request on Google App Engine test server (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, httprequest, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to make an application using Google App Engine. Part of the functionality requires me to pull calendar data from a 3rd party server via http. It is important to note that **the server I'm connecting to does not use ssl**. So the target url contains only "http://".

Anyway, I wrote some code in a normal Java Application as a proof of concept.

```
    try {

        // Create url
        URL targetUrl = new URL(target);

        // Open the connection
        URLConnection connection = targetUrl.openConnection();

        // Create InputStream
        InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();

        // Parse calendar data using iCal4j
        CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
        theCalendar = builder.build(inStream);

        // Close the connection
        inStream.close();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So I ran this code in the Java Application and it worked like a charm. After seeing it work, I decided to try to implement the same code into into a test servlet I created inside of my Google App Engine project. However, upon allowing it to execute, I get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for URL: http://the_url
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:175)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:543)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:422)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
at com.amftech.website.CalendarServlet.doGet(CalendarServlet.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I also noticed that upon launching the server, the following warnings were outputted:

```
Jun 12, 2017 2:43:14 PM com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil supportsUnsafeByteBufferOperations
WARNING: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc")
Jun 12, 2017 2:43:14 PM com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil supportsUnsafeArrayOperations
WARNING: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc")
Jun 12, 2017 2:43:14 PM com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil supportsUnsafeCopyMemory
WARNING: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
```

I don't know if those warnings mean anything, but I thought they might. Is there a problem with my test server setup? My project setup? I have searched the whole internet and haven't found anything except for "make sure you download the certificate". But the server that I'm connecting to doesn't even use SSL, so why is it complaining about an SSL handshake?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm not sure what was going on, but I think my setup was messed up somehow. I was able to fix this problem by deleting Eclipse, uninstalling the Google Cloud SDK, uninstalling java, resetting my workspace in Eclipse, and reinstalling and reconfiguring everything. So I hope I could help someone with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you updated to java8 runtime in Google App Engine, you need to have a setting on your appengine-web.xml. For more information on that, look at [java.net.UnknownHostException: appengine.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912998/java-net-unknownhostexception-appengine-google-com)